# `worldViewProjection` doesn't work for a single component

Tags: webgl, camera-matrix

I have implemented a couple of classes which are drawn using shaders where the vertex position is always calculated the same way:

`gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * a_position;`

The `u_worldViewProjection`-uniform is calculated using a `viewProjectionMatrix` which comes from a camera class. This is how I calculate the `viewProjectionMatrix`:

```
const projectionMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.perspective(projectionMatrix, this._fieldOfViewRadians, this._aspect, this._zNear, this._zFar);
mat4.rotateY(projectionMatrix, projectionMatrix, MathHelper.degToRad(this._cameraAngleDeg));

// Setup camera
const cameraMatrix = mat4.create();
const up = vec3.fromValues(0, 1, 0);
mat4.lookAt(cameraMatrix, this._cameraPosition, this._viewDirection, up);

const viewProjectionMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.multiply(viewProjectionMatrix, projectionMatrix, cameraMatrix);

return viewProjectionMatrix;
```

After that I would draw some component where I would set the `u_worldViewProjection`-uniform something like this:

```
protected _calculateMatrixData(viewProjectionMatrix: mat4): void {
// Set the world-matrix aka model matrix, position rotation and scaling
const worldMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.translate(worldMatrix, worldMatrix, this.translation);
mat4.scale(worldMatrix, worldMatrix, vec3.fromValues(this._scale[0], this._scale[1], this._scale[2]));
mat4.rotateX(worldMatrix, worldMatrix, MathHelper.degToRad(this._rotationAngleDegree[0]));
mat4.rotateY(worldMatrix, worldMatrix, MathHelper.degToRad(this._rotationAngleDegree[1]));
mat4.rotateZ(worldMatrix, worldMatrix, MathHelper.degToRad(this._rotationAngleDegree[2]));

this._worldMatrixData.value = worldMatrix;

// Create worldViewProjection matrix
const worldViewProjectionMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.multiply(worldViewProjectionMatrix, viewProjectionMatrix, worldMatrix);
// ...
// set the uniforms some time later
```

Until now this worked for every object. Now I introduced a new shader-pair:

#### vertex shader:

```
#version 300 es

in vec4 a_position;
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;

void main() {

  gl_PointSize = 10.5;
  gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * a_position;
}
```

#### fragment shader:

```
#version 300 es

// Set fragment shader's precision to "medium precision"
precision mediump float;

out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
  outColor = vec4(1, 0, 0.1, 0.5);
}
```

Seems simple. The problem is those do not render the component. I did realize that the component is being drawn if I omit the `u_worldViewProjection` in the `gl_Position` calculation.

`gl_Position = a_position;`

The above snippet will draw the component, but of course this will not take any changes in account that were made to the camera. Thus I guess that my `u_worldViewProjection` is the source of the false behaviour.

This is how I calculate the `worldViewProjectionMatrix` for the above shaders:

```
const worldMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.scale(worldMatrix, worldMatrix, vec3.fromValues(1.0, 1.0, 1.0));

// Create worldViewProjection matrix
const worldViewProjectionMatrix = mat4.create();
mat4.multiply(worldViewProjectionMatrix, viewProjectionMatrix, worldMatrix);
```

The resulting matrix is **not** null or undefined.

I know it is kind of impossible to point out the origin of the problem but maybe there some approach to find the source or maybe I am doing something completely wrong?

Any help would be appreciated. If there is some other information I should provide please let me know.

Comment: two things that bother me with your matrix calculations: 1. you rotate your `projectionMatrix` around the camera angle - but you also use `LookAt` for your view matrix, which would include the `_cameraAngleDeg`, wouldn't it? in fact, I don't see why you want to rotate your `projectionMatrix` at all, in theory your viewing position and direction of looking is set up with the `viewMatrix`. The second thing is the order of transformations in your `worldMatrix`. You should probably scale before you rotate an object.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This was entirely my fault. I simply forgot to set the uniform locations before rendering!

I implemented a function `setUniformLocations()` which sets the uniform locations passed to it:

```
public static setUniformLocations(
    gl: WebGL2RenderingContext, 
    uniforms: IUniform[], 
    program: WebGLProgram): IUniform[] {

    const vao = gl.createVertexArray();
    gl.bindVertexArray(vao);

    for (const uniform of uniforms) {
        uniforms.find((u) => u.name === uniform.name).location = gl.getUniformLocation(program, uniform.name);
    }

    return uniforms;
}
```

I normally call this function in the constructor of the according class.

```
this._uniforms = GLHelper.setUniformLocations(this.gl, this._uniforms, this._program);
```

This time I forgot.

Comment: May I ask why the downvotes?